# Symfony, log without explicit error at every page

Tags: php, symfony, logging

I face a strange problem here with symfony. Indeed, since a few days I struggle with this "bug" : At every page of my application I load, I have no errors on the page, everything is perfect BUT symfony write somes logs in the dev.log file. I read them but there is only thrown and catched events, no errors, I do not know where to search but this is a problem because the dev.log file grow really fast ^^. Maybe someone faced the same problem ? Or can fins something in the dev.log : I also have FOSRestbundle/wsse, but can find nothing in it...

```
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\BodyListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] request.INFO: Matched route "romain_general_homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "Romain\GeneralBundle\Controller\GeneralController::presentationAction", "_route": "romain_general_homepage") [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] security.DEBUG: Username "Voyager" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\ParamFetcherListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\ViewResponseListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener   "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ChromePhpHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\BodyListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt" (parameters: "_controller": "web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction", "token": "6e72f6", "_route": "_wdt") [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\ParamFetcherListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\ViewResponseListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ChromePhpHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:32] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
```

and on doctrine_dev.log (I separated the files...)

```
[2014-04-23 21:14:27] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17, t0.nom AS nom18, t0.prenom AS prenom19, t0.termes AS termes20 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ? LIMIT 1 [1] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.nom AS nom2, t0.localisation AS localisation3, t0.dateCreation AS dateCreation4, t0.proprietaire_id AS proprietaire_id5 FROM groupe t0 INNER JOIN groupe_user ON t0.id = groupe_user.groupe_id WHERE groupe_user.user_id = ? [1] []
[2014-04-23 21:14:29] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.dateCreation AS dateCreation2, t0.description AS description3, t0.type AS type4, t0.criticite AS criticite5, t0.vu AS vu6, t0.info AS info7, t0.user_id AS user_id8 FROM notification t0 WHERE t0.user_id = ? [1] []
```

So am I the only one ? I think there is a bug with no log and not visible on the page.
Anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log files don't have to contain only errors, but various types of messages. Those you pasted are debug messages. You could change `dev` environment configuration not to do it but I see no reason why would you.

If you use your application in `prod` environment (without app_dev.php) debug messages won't be logged.

Comment: Yes... indeed you are right. But it bothers me more than it should. I think I did not have all this log before. So that's why this file is so laaaaaaarge everytime. Thanks